# Excel VBA: Formula Syntax to refer to Worksheet Index Number (Relative Instead of Name)

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a macro that will filter a database (updated daily) and compute specific formulas. Each time the macro is ran, a new sheet (uniquely named) will be created with the filtered information, and the calculations will be performed on an additional sheet.

I am having trouble creating a macro with the correct syntax. Each time the macro is run, the filtered data I need to reference is located on worksheet #3 (uniquely named). I'm new to VBA and don't understand the syntax I need to reference the worksheet(index) as the worksheet in an R1C1 formula. Right now, my code looks like this:

```
Dim LR As Long

   LR = Worksheets(3).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row  

   Range("G6").Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _ 
      "=COUNTIF(='Worksheets(3)'!R6C5:R" & LR &"C5,R[-1]C"
```

The code is counting if a column of Years (of a variable length) is equal to R[-1]C, which is a cell that contains a certain year, and will display the count in cell G6.

Is it possible to use a worksheet(index) reference in this context? How else could I accomplish the task of referencing a worksheet without name? Would I need to reference a "name" variable?

Comment: There really isn't any penalty to using full column references with countif unless you have values below the ones you want that could produce skewed results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had an extra `=` sign in there and you seem to be missing a closing bracket but .Address external:=true produces a nice range reference.

```
Dim LR As Long, str as string

with Worksheets(3)
    LR = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
    str = .range(.cells(6, 5), .cells(lr, 5)).address(external:=true, ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
end with

Range("G6").FormulaR1C1 = _ 
  "=COUNTIF(" & str & ", R[-1]C)"
```